# 2nd largest no. in python list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm a beginner in python and I've been solving this problem to find the second largest element of a python list. There are a no. of ways to solve this problem but the way I tried to solve it was removing the largest value (no matter how many times it would be present in the list) and then printing the maximum value of the modified list.

```
n = int(input("Enter the no. of list entries"))
list_students = []
for i in range(0, n):
    the_input = int(input("Enter the list element"))
    list_students.append(the_input)

highest = max(list_students)

for i in list_students:
    print("Considering",i)
    if i==highest:
       print("to be deleted ",i)
       list_students.remove(i)
print("the max value is",max(list_students))

Output-

Enter the list element 4
Enter the list element 4
Enter the list element 4
Enter the list element 3
Enter the list element 1
Considering 4
to be deleted  4
Considering 4
to be deleted  4
Considering 1
the max value is 4
```

While it was expected to be 3. It can be clearly seen that the loop doesn't even consider the third 4 and its neighboring element which is 3. And it happens every time no matter how many times the highest element is repeatedly entered. Can anyone please explain the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The function `remove` remove the first matching value, not your current value you are testing in the loop. So you are modifying the list in the same time that you go through it.
What you could try is to call `remove(highest)` until its value is changed.

Like this:

```
 while max(list_students) == highest:
      list_students.remove(highest)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the strange behavior you're observing is that you're removing items from a list you're iterating through, so by moving items from the iterated list you make the iteration skip certain items, since what was considered the next item disappeared.

To fix your code without rewriting it, you can simply make a copy of the list before iterating through it:

```
for i in list_students.copy():
```